# Enabling a default "pre-revprop-change" hook for new repositories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Whenever I create an SVN repository (I'm using TortoiseSVN) I wish it would apply my standard pre-revprop-change.bat file in the hooks directory.  I use this to enable things like allowing edits to log messages.

**Is there some way to create a "default" pre-revprop-change.bat that gets added automatically upon repo creation?**

I found this question that has a similar title, but the question appears to be more about why something wasn't working that the author thought could be fixed by automatically applying the hook script.

Answer (score 0):

1. You **can not** (at least - easy) override TSVN's context menu
2. You **can** create repositories not using TSVN, but with bat-file (`svnadmin create ...; copy ...`)